# Memmove with SSE

Tags: visual-c++, sse, simd, memmove

I have to move up to 8KB of data where source and destination can overlap.
I might call this code for few million times per sec.
Machines running my code will have at least SSE3.
Does memmove in Visual Studio 2012 already use these instructions or could I benefit from custom implementation?
Is there any alternative implementation available?
I'm targeting mostly x64 machines.

Comment: There is an optimized implementation in Agner Fog's asmlib: http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip

Comment: MSVC's CRT uses SSE2 based variants if SSE2 is available, unfortunatly it checks a global every time you call it, so its better to use `/arch:SSE2` and assignment